# ios ipad simulator passing arguments to app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I've managed to get the ios simulator to run my app, my app takes a command line argument supplying a path to load data files from on my mac, this works ok launching the simulator from xcode but when I run the simulator from command line it returns unable to find the first file I load in code:

**Terminal Output**

> cannot open -RegisterForSystemEvents/myconfigdata.txt"

**My command line is:**

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\
>   Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone\ Simulator -SimulateApplication
>   myios.app/myios --family ipad --args "/Users/chris.x/mydatapath/"

I'm passing the path I use in xcode with the **--args** parameter

Any ideas?

TIA

Comment: Why do you want to launch it from command line anyway? Just curious!

Comment: Prem, so I can give my app to someone else, they can easily specify the path to the data they want to run (there could be several sets of data) and it means the data doesn't have to be rebundled each change, and they dont have to set the argument in xcode / run the ios sim from xcode. The command line appears an easier way to run it. Can you see a better way to do this?